# Shortcuts how to send parameter

Tags: android, shortcut

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="owner"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/owner"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/owner"
        android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/owner">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetPackage="com.ap.ap"
            android:targetClass="com.ap.ap.LoginActivity" />
        <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
             here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
             they launch this shortcut. -->
        <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
    </shortcut>
    <!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
</shortcuts>
```

In manifest i defined

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
```

and its appearing and working.However the problem lies, how can i send a parameter value with this to LoginActivity that its clicked from the shortcut.I want to send a value like intent.putextra("owner","ds");